# need help about solving differential equation

Tags: matlab

I have tried to solve this following program in `matlab` but failed.

```
clear all
syms y(x)
y=dsolve(2.5e-3*diff(y, 2) + 0.5*diff(y) +122.5*y == 2570);
y=0 , y=20 ;
```

I want to find value of y.

Comment: Failed how? Wrong Results? Issue with running? Be more specific

Comment: This is unclear. _"but falied"_ are ambiguous words. Please explain how this did not work. Runtime error, compiler error, etc. Till you post the necessary details, we cannot help you. Please post complete questions, with complete details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is not simply a copy-past error, you need to specify the location of the boundary values (or potentially initial conditions).  The easiest way to do this is within the call to `dsolve` itself (since I don't know the locations, I'm going to assume *y = 0* at *x = 0* and *y = 20* at *x = 1/50*):

```
syms x y(x)
xa = sym(0);
xb = sym('1/50');
y(x) = dsolve(2.5e-3*diff(y, 2) + 0.5*diff(y) + 122.5*y == 2570,y(xa)==0 , y(xb)==20)
```